# Why autowiring doesn't work?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm Working on a Spring web App with Hibernate and Spring Mvc, And I'm wondering why Autowiring works only inside of the controller 
this is a simple example :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="SW/excel")
public class ExcelController
{
   @Autowired
   private BlablaService blablaService;
   @RequestMapping({""})
   public ModelAndView indexPage()
   {
     List<Blabla> blablas=BlablaService.getAllBlablas();
   }
}
```

This code is working fine for me, it returns the list of *Blablas* I have in my Database.
but when I work with my BlablaService outside of the controller, it doesn't work and here is and example

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping(value="SW/excel")
public class ExcelController
{
   @RequestMapping({""})
   public ModelAndView indexPage()
   {
     BlablaLister lister= new ExcelExporter();
     List<Blabla> blablas=lister.getList();
   }

}
```

And here is the Excel Exporter:

```
Class BlablaLister {
@Autowired BlablaService blablaService;
public List<Blabla> getList()
   {
      return blablaService.getAllBlablas;
   }
}
```

But I always get , NullPointerException, the getAllBlablas returns Null whenever used in the a class out of the controller.

Comment: Shouldn't it be @Controller or is there a french Spring version @Controlleur? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `BlablaLister` have to be initiated via spring in order for autowiring to work

Comment: why the autowired service work in the controller, assuming that I didn't any configuration to initiate the controller via spring ?

Comment: You did actually, by marking it a @Controller and using component scan in your spring config spring will automatically pick it up

Comment: according to Spring documentation if I add @Component to my class, it will be automatically picked as Aidan suggested, but I've got the same issue...

Comment: BlablaLister lister= new ExcelExporter(); this is the offending line, even that you added your class to spring via the annotation it is still not instantiating with spring, try autowiring the ExcelExporter class into your controller, then it should work or request it from the Spring context

Comment: Thanks! by the way, why my question is down voted :(

Answer (score 2):

In order for the autowiring to work Spring must know about the object - either by having it instantiated in the config file or by using one of the annotations that instantiate a bean. To make it work you probably just need to add the @Component annotation to identify it as a spring-managed bean.

```
@Component
Class BlablaLister {
@Autowired BlablaService blablaService;
public List<Blabla> getList()
   {
      return blablaService.getAllBlablas;
   }
}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating your BlablaLister?  Are you requesting it from the spring context or are you just creating an instance.  You need to request the instance from the spring context.